# How do I use a for loop to open .ncdf files and average a matrix variable that has different values over all the files? (Using R Programming)

Tags: r, nco

I'm currently trying to code an averaged matrix for all matrix values from a specific air quality variable (ColumnAmountNO2TropCloudScreened) positioned in different .ncdf4 files. The only way I was able to do it was listing all the files, opening them using lapply, creating a single NO2 variable for every ncdf. file and then applying abind to all of the variables. Even though I was able to do it, it took me a lot of time to type in different names for the NO2 variables (NO2_1, NO2_2,NO2_3,etc) and which row to access the original listed file ([[1]],[[2]],[[3]],etc).

I am trying to type in a code that's smarter and easier than just typing in a bunch of numbers. I have all the original .ncdf4 files listed, and am trying to loop over the files to open them and get the 'ColumnAmountNO2TropCloudScreened' matrix value from each, so then I can average them. However, I am having no luck. Would someone know what is wrong with this code/my thought over it? Thanks.

I'm trying the code as it follows:

```
# Load libraries 
library(ncdf4)
library(abind)
library(plot.matrix)
# Set working directory
setwd("~/researchdatasets/2020")
# Declare data frame
df=NULL
# List all files in one file
files1= list.files(pattern='\\.nc4$',full.names=FALSE)
# Loop to open files, get NO2 variables 
for(i in seq(along=files1)) {
  nc_data = nc_open(files1[i])
  NO2_var<-ncvar_get(nc_data,'ColumnAmountNO2TropCloudScreened')
  nc_close(nc_data)
}
# Average variables 
list_NO2= apply(abind::abind(NO2_var,along=3),1:2,mean,na.rm=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

NCO's [ncra](https://nco.sf.net/nco.html#ncra) averages variables across all input files with, e.g.,

```
ncra in*.nc out.nc
```